# How to target specific ui-view inside ng-repeat (or do this differently)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm new to angular and have run into a very basic problem

```
<div ng-reapeat="thing in things">
  <div class="title">{{thing.title}}</div>
  <div class="more-text" ui-view></div>
</div>
```

on routechange to, say, `"/something"` I'd like to add some text into `"more-text"` ui-view into one particular `"thing's"` ui-view, but it gets added in every instance of ui-view. Ten times if there are ten things.

Basically, I'd like to fill out some text into a `div` inside a repeat, but I don't know how to target a specific ui-view if its repeated.

But maybe there is a much better way to do this?

thanks!
J

Comment: scope for each repeated element gets a `$last` and `$first` property... can add what you want when true

Comment: you probably use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) so it would be nice to specify it in your question as it is an external module.

Comment: Same issue here have you found a solution? thanks